# Date field showing January, 01 1900 00:00:00 though I set it to blank

Tags: sql-server

When I use the below statement to set the  `TD_BOOK_COMPLETED_ON` to blank , it gives me January, 01 1900 00:00:00 , how can I set my Date field to ''?

**Code:**

```
case when BOOK_COMPLETED='Y' then TD_BOOK_COMPLETED_ON else '' end as END_DATE
```

Comment: You can't. None of the date/time data types will accommodate an empty string value. Your options are to leave it as null or use an appropriate date/time value.

Answer (score 2):

An empty string literal is shorthand for the [default datetime value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql), which is `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. Only valid datetime values in the documented range, or NULL, can be stored in a datetime column.

Instead of an empty string, you probably want to use `NULL` to indicate unknown or not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

A date is not a string. Set it to NULL instead. It's interpreting an empty space '' as a 0, which is 1/1/1900.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `CAST` or `CONVERT` the date to `VARCHAR`

```
CASE when BOOK_COMPLETED='Y' then CAST(TD_BOOK_COMPLETED_ON AS VARCHAR(24)) else '' end as END_DATE
```

or set the date to `NULL`